# JQgrid baselinkURL options

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

```
jQuery("#grid_id").jqGrid({
    ...
    colModel: [
      {name:'myname', formatter:'showlink',
        formatoptions: {
            baseLinkUrl:'someurl.php', addParam: '&action=edit', idName:'myid'
        },
        ...
      }
    ... 
    ]
    ...
});
```

This will produce a link to `domain/someurl.php?myid=123&action=edit`.
How can I specify the form value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The line](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.5.2/js/jquery.fmatter.js#L158) of source code shows how the URL used in `href` attribute of the link will be constructed:

```
idUrl = op.baseLinkUrl+op.showAction + '?'+ op.idName+'='+opts.rowId+op.addParam;
```

In your case it will be

```
"someurl.php?myid=" + rowid + "&action=edit"
```

If you specify correctly the rowid in the input data for the grid then the `showlink` should do almost what you expect. You don't describe *which problem you have*. If `showlink` works not like you expect you should append the text of your question with details about *how you fill the grid* how you specify *id* of rows, include test data and describe which problem you see.